# System.Text.Json Custom JsonConverter never called

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I wanted to migrate from Newtonsoft an Asp net core project. I must use a JsonConverter to keep some old functionality.

I have tried calling my custom converter on a property, on a type and on startup as I read in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#registration-sample---jsonconverter-on-a-property); It never seems to be called.

I created a sample project just to be sure it was not something else. If the converter executes either the Write or Read methods it should throw an exception. But so far I have not been able to make them execute.

Here is the code for the converter

```
public class MyCustomConverter : JsonConverter<FooProp>
{
    public override FooProp Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        FooProp value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The code of the controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    public WeatherForecastController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(new FooClass());
    }

    public class FooClass
    {
        public string Always {get; set;}
        // Adds on property
        [JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomConverter))]
        public FooProp Sometimes {get; set;}
    }

    // Adds on type
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomConverter))]
    public class FooProp
    {
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the code for startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => {
            // Adds on startup
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new MyCustomConverter());
        });
}
```

The .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

It seems so simple, I must be doing an obvious mistake, but I have been at this for a while unable to find what im doing wrong.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The converter is never called because `FooClass.Sometimes` is `null` by default, and you never allocated it.  `WriteJson()` is only called on non-null values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have tried calling my custom converter on a property, on a type and
>   on startup as I read in the docs; It never seems to be called.

That is because your custom `JsonConverter` inherits the `JsonConverter<FooProp>` which can only convert `FooProp` class:

```
public class MyCustomConverter : JsonConverter<FooProp>
```

You returned new FooClass,it would create null `Sometimes`. 
Just change the following code then you could see the exception:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    //return Ok(new FooProp());
    return Ok(new FooClass { Sometimes = new FooProp() });
}
```

Comment: That will do it but it's only partly the reason. `new FooClass()` will result in `Sometimes` being `null` and therefore the converter isn't called. If you use something like `new FooClass { Sometimes = new FooProp() };` you should see the exception as well.

Comment: its not getting called even with generic type used in converter, so I am not sure this is the only cause